# Unsupported operand type on Time series management

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, formatting, tsfresh

Today, I will to manage my time series dataset for using the library TSfresh and make time series classification.

I use [this tutorial](https://iq.opengenus.org/time-series-classification/), to adapt the code to my data.
For now, I realize some steps, but one error occurs in the splitting data :

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Import the data path (my time series path)
data_path = 'PATH'

#Import the csv containing the label (in my case "Reussite_Sevrage")
target_df = pd.read_csv("PATH.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1", dtype={'ID': 'str'})

# Delete the useless lines (containing nan values in the end of the dataset)
target_df = target_df.iloc[0:57,:]

# Definition of the labels
labels = target_df['Reussite_sevrage']

# Definition of the df containing the IDs
sequence_ids=target_df['ID']


#Splitting the data 
train_ids, test_ids, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(sequence_ids, labels, test_size=0.2)

#Create the X_train and X_test dataframe
X_train = pd.DataFrame()
X_test = pd.DataFrame()

# Now, will loop through the training sequence IDs and the testing sequence IDs. 
# For each of these sequence IDs, we will read the corresponding time series data CSV file and add it to the main dataframe.
# We will also add a column for the sequence number and a step column which contains integers representing the time step in the sequence

for i, sequence in enumerate(train_ids):
    inputfile = 'PATH'/ f"{sequence}.txt"
    if inputfile.exists():
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_path, 'PAD/', "%s.txt" % sequence), 
                delimiter='\t',  # columns are separated by spaces
                header=None,  # there's no header information
                #parse_dates=[[0, 1]],  # the first and second columns should be combined and converted to datetime objects
                #infer_datetime_format=True,
                decimal=",")
        df = df.iloc[:,1]
        df = df.to_frame(name ='values')
        df.insert(0, 'sequence', i)
        df['step'] = np.arange(df.shape[0]) # creates a range of integers starting from 0 to the number of the measurements.
        X_train = pd.concat([X_train, df])
```

I add a condition in the loop to check and process only the files existing. The missing data are represent by a missing files. If I omit this condition, the loop stop when it detect a missing files.

```
inputfile = PATH / f"{sequence}.txt"
    if inputfile.exists():
```

But this errors occurs :
`unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`

I don't know if the error is due to the `dtype={'ID': 'str'}` during the data loading, but i need it, because the ID are formated like that : 0001, 0002, 0003... If I don't add this condition, the ID are converted in : 1,2,3...

The `sequence_ids, train_ids, train_labels, test_ids and test_labels` are series format, and `sequence` are str format.

Can you have a solution for this problem please ?

Thank you very much

Comment: The error says you cant divide 2 strings. Meaning, `str / str` is not allowed. In your case youre doing `"PATH" / f"{sequence}.txt"`. What is the variable `inputfile` supposed to be?

Comment: I think your `inputfile` should be `os.path.join(data_path, 'PAD/', "%s.txt" % sequence)`

Comment: The inputfile are the path containing all the files, and I add the term ```sequence``` to verify if the ID in  present in the series "train_ids" are really present in this path. 
I try your solution but I have an another error : ```'str' object has no attribute 'exists'```

Comment: I would suggest using `Path` library to deal with file paths. You can import `from pathlib import Path` and `inputfile` will be `Path("PATH") / f"PAD/{sequence}.txt"` This will create a Path object to the path of the sequence file. Now you should be able to call `exists()` method on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Path library to deal with file paths. You can import using `from pathlib import Path` and `inputfile` will be `Path(data_path) / f"PAD/{sequence}.txt"` This will create a Path object to the path of the sequence file. Now you should be able to call `exists()` method on this.

Final code:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Import the data path (my time series path)
data_path = 'PATH'

...


for i, sequence in enumerate(train_ids):
    inputfile = Path(data_path) / f"PAD/{sequence}.txt"
    
    if inputfile.exists():
        df = pd.read_csv(
            inputfile, 
            delimiter='\t',  # columns are separated by spaces
            header=None,  # there's no header information
            decimal=","
        )

        ...
```